# Does EventGridTrigger wors in App service plan and ASE?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-ase

I have an Event Grid Trigger Azure function deployed to a function app which is in an ASE. I have created an event grid subscription with this function as an end point. The purpose of this subscription is to call this function once a blob file is created.

When I placed the file in the location, the event is supposed to call the function but I see the event is undelivered.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Before asking next question please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you are not able to understand the issue? @DanielBjörk

Comment: There is not enough details in your question to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check now please

Comment: Place the file where? What code is listening/expected to take care of the response and so on... Help us to help you.

Comment: There is an event grid subscription that should trigger an azure function (C#) adn performs some operations whenever a file is placed in a blob folder in a container. This works fine if the function is not inside an ASE. It doesn't work if the function is in ASE.

Comment: Have a look here, same problem with more information: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44123

Comment: I have checked this article and I didn't get much from it.

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve your problem?

Comment: Nothing. I do not know where to start with. And the article you have shared tells us that an event cannot trigger azure function which is placed in an ASE. I have posted this to see if there is any work around

Comment: No the MSFT actually said the opposite. 

"Hello. Because Event Grid does not support service endpoints it cannot be accessed through virtual network integration. You can however access it through the public endpoint while virtual network integration is enabled for your Function app.
This should work just fine today with no additional configuration required."

Comment: If you see the last comment in the article, the user said "We can publish events to the topic, but while adding subscription it fails with 403 forbidden error, we can not create subscription when function app is integrated with vnet. After disconnecting the vnet from function app I was able to add the event grid subscription.

Also when vnet is enabled events won't be delivered to the subscription(function residing inside vnet)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an eventgrid subscription that writes the event to a queue whenever a file is created in blob. I have modified exiting EvenGridTrigger function to QueueTrigger function. Both storage account and function app are in same vnet.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in Azure documents :

> " When your **function** app runs in either an App Service plan or an App Service Environment, you can use non-HTTP trigger functions. For your functions to get triggered correctly, you must be connected to a virtual network with access to the resource defined in the trigger connection. "

Maybe you can refer to this article.[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#regional-virtual-network-integration)